# class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter

Tags: jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I am using primefaces 6.0 and WebSphere 8.0 and i want to implement GZip in my webApp. After lot of research i came to know using omnifaces GzipResponseFilter i can use Gzip compression technique. 
here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>pla.web</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>gzipResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>The threshold size in bytes. Must be a number between 0 and 9999. Defaults to 150.</description>
        <param-name>threshold</param-name>
        <param-value>150</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <description>The mimetypes which needs to be compressed. Must be a commaseparated string. Defaults to the below values.</description>
        <param-name>mimetypes</param-name>
        <param-value>
     text/plain, text/html, text/xml, text/css, text/javascript, text/csv, text/rtf,
     application/xml, application/xhtml+xml, application/x-javascript, application/javascript, application/json,
     image/svg+xml, image/gif, application/x-font-woff, application/font-woff2, image/png
 </param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>gzipResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/</location>
</error-page>   

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- do not render comments -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- do not ignore empty input fields -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- validate also empty fields -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>daimler</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>128</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Error seems simple and clear to me, the class you refer to is not in your runtime project.

Answer (score 0):

org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter has not been found in your build path. Inspect your build path and correct the set-up.